# Node.js, Expressjs, Mongo, Jade: `new` action passing initialized mongo instance resulting in 'ReferenceError: jade is not defined'

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, pug

Source: [github](https://github.com/davidglivar/simplecompviewer)

In trying to pass a freshly instantiated mongoose.model through expressjs' `render` function, I come upon the following error: "ReferenceError: jade is not defined"

The controller...

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose")
  , Client = mongoose.model("Client")

exports.new = function (req, res) {
    res.render("clients/new", {
        headline: "New Client",
        client: new Client({})
    })
}
```

I have also tried `client: new Client()`, storing the instantiated object in a var then passing it to the final render object with no change. Removing the `new Client({})` bit gets past the 500 error, but does not solve the issue at hand.

Some config...

```
app.set("views", __dirname + "/app/views")
app.set("view engine", "jade")
```

The model...

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose")
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema

var Client = new Schema({
    company: { type: String },
    contact: {
        name: { type: String },
        phone: { type: String },
        email: { type: String }
    },
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})

mongoose.model("Client", Client)
```

Node v0.8.12
Express >= v3.0.0
Mongoose v3.3.1
Jade v0.27.6

Source: [github](https://github.com/davidglivar/simplecompviewer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is obviously caused by a keyword clash within the jade template engine.

I found your problem description interesting enough to try it out myself. After changing the jade template variable identifier `client` to `myclient` and passing a new mongoose `Client` model instance everything worked fine:

In app/controllers/clients_controller:

```
...
res.render("clients/new", {
    headline: "New Client",
    myclient: new Client({company: 'Foo Company'})
})
...
```

In views/clients/new:

```
...
input(type='text',name='company',placeholder='Company',value='#{myclient.company}')
...
```

I forked your repository, committed those changes and send you a pull request (first and foremost because I'm relatively new to git and grab every chance to learn some more basics).

Comment: Perfect! Dang keywords. (btw, merged your pull request) Thanks for the help!